# Why would @SessionsScoped EJB be shared accross all users?

Tags: jakarta-ee, return, java-ee-6, cdi

I am sure I am missing something here.. but I have a session scoped EJB:

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.ejb.Stateful
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class Authenticator implements Serializable
{
...
```

I would expect that each HTTP session would see a different instance of this EJB?

However, when accessing a JSF page from multiple browsers (including on different machines), the output of

```
#{authenticator.hashCode()}
```

is the same on all of them (and of course the class's member attributes). Why would this be? (I have experimented with removing @Stateful annotation, but the same applies).

I am using JBoss AS 7.1.0.

EDIT: I have discovered that creating a method on Authenticator:

```
public void getHashCode()
{
   return hashCode();
}
```

and referencing this in the EL as

```
#{authenticator.hashCode()}
```

shows that I am actually accessing different instances of the bean; but why is this? I cannot understand why the results of these two EL expressions would be different.

Comment: Does the Authenticator class have a field that's unique to the session, such as the session ID? If not, there's nothing to indicate that they **are** the exact same instance, and aren't instead two distinct instances that have the same values for their fields.

Comment: That's what I was using hashCode for - that should be different. Also, if you login on one browser it is then showing the logged in user on the other, which is what alerted me to the problem in the first place.

Comment: Any chance that you have static members in your bean?

Comment: Yes, I think this was the issue for the member attributes (also one was annotated @Produces on the field rather than the get method). However, I am still unclear why hashCode() returns the same value - this is not static, is it?

Comment: Different objects aren't required to have different hash values. `return 0;` is a perfectly valid, though not a very good, `hashCode()` implementation. That said, it's possible that you're running into a proxy. Your first experiment may be getting the hash value of the proxy. Your second experiment makes it through to the object instance and returns its hash value. I'm not sure why a proxy would come into play in this case, but I think the behavior fits.

Comment: I think that the proxy suggestion makes sense (I am convinced that the default hashCode implementation wouldn't be returning identical 10 digit numbers in this instance).  I would really like to know why the EL is hitting a proxy for #{authenticator.hashCode}, but not for #{authenticator.getHashCode}, though!

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're seeing is consistent with having unauthenticated HTTP sessions, so I assume you don't have authentication set up. Therefore, if you add the following to your code

```
@Resource
private EJBContext ctx;

public Principal getPrincipal() {
    return this.ctx.getCallerPrincipal();
}
```

and in your test page you add

```
<h:outputText value="#{test.principal}" />
<h:outputText value="#{test.hashCode()}" />
```

you'll always see the same output. To the EJB container, since in local calls the client is actually the servlet container, you'll always see the same output `ANONYMOUS{your hash code here}`. Each unauthenticated http session counts as one `ANONIMOUS` EJB session, since the client is always the same - your servlet container.

Try setting up some sort of authentication and you'll see the behaviour you expect, at least I do in my Glassfish3+ environment.